# Redirect folder on parked domain to main domain

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I am moving a client's site from static HTMl to a WordPress site. This has also involved setting up a new domain. I have the legacy domain set up as a parked domain on my server and can successfully redirect all requests for the parked domain to the main domain. Here is my .htaccess in full:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Rewrite from parked domain to new domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^parked-domain.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.parked-domain.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.main-domain\.co\.uk" [R=301,L]

# All requests hit www.domain.co.uk to prevent duplicate content
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.main-domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.main-domain.co.uk$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, I am coming unstuck when I try to redirect requests for specific pages on the parked domain to pages at the main domain.

For example, requests for parked-domain.co.uk/html/about_us.html should redirect to main-domain.co.uk/about-us/

I've a hit a brick wall (in spite of many hours of forum-searching) and any help would be gratefully received; this is rage-inducing.

Comment: Your "parked" RewriteRules seem to be redundant. Anything which would be matched by that rule would also be matched by the last set of rules. That doesn't help your specific problem but it seems like extra clutter

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I translated the file incorrectly and the final rule is actually: anotherdomain.co.uk :)

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you simply add

> [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)`/html/about_us.html http://www.main-domain.co.uk/about_us.html`

to that file?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, Gareth, but that leads to a 500 error. Wouldn't what you have written assume that the RewriteBase is parked-domain.co.uk? I have attempted multiple combos of what seems like obvious solutions to no avail. I wonder if anyone has encountered this circumstance and has coded a solution?

Comment: `Redirect` is separate to the `mod_rewrite` engine (it's provided by `mod_alias`) so it shouldn't conflict with that at all. What 500 error does this give you? Hopefully you can check the error logs in your setup because that's where the detailed messages sit.